# Android full screen fragment, detecting back key

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having an issue with the back stack on fragments.

I am using SlidingMenu with ActionBarSHerlock. Everything works fine

i have a list view in a fragment, on selecting item in list view i show another list view. No problems so far.

But, i want to set a title for each list view, which works except when i go back from a fragment

Scenario

Fragment 1 - Title is "Friend Groups"

On tapping a list item  Fragment 2 is shown. Before showing it i set the title for Fragment 2 as "Friends in Group" - This works well too

However, when i press the back key in Fragment 2 and when Fragment 1 comes into view i want to change the title back to "Friend Groups"

I have tried setting onKeyListener in Fragment 2, but does'nt work. How can i detect back key inside Fragment 2?

Comment: are you using fragment transaction?

Comment: Yes i am, as i have mentioned i have no issues with the fragments itself, I am stuck with handling the Back Key.

Comment: try overriding onBackPressed()

Comment: Thanks. i have tried that, but it is not called inside a fragment.

Comment: I think that is a major known bug. I ran into this in the past. Maybe you can override onBackPressed in your activity and then have the activity alert your fragments when this happens. I know for sure that the host activity will be called when back is pressed.

Comment: Yeah the host activity receives the backpressed event, i was hoping to find a way for a fragment to grab it before the host activity